# How do i remove properties from object which doesnt exist in array?

Tags: javascript

Lets say that we have an object with properties 1,3,5

lets say we have an array = [1,3]

how do i remove 5 from object so our object will be 1,3 properties and their values ?

[from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51JvV.png)

Comment: How do you _think_ you should do it, and what have you _tried_? Can you add in your code to the question as an [mcve], please?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `typescript`?

Comment: The `delete` syntax can be used to remove properties from objects. Something like `delete obj[ '5' ]`. But it's usually better to just create a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = {1 : 1, 3 : 3,  5 : 5},
    arr = [1, 3]

Object.keys(obj).forEach((v)=> {
  if(arr.indexOf(Number(v)) === -1) delete obj[v]
})

console.log(obj)
```